# How to change the time format when providing an initial value in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms

I made a form in Django and provided an initial value to the time field when rendering the form, the format is HH:MM:SS but if I do not provide any initial value the format is HH:MM. I want to specify an initial value and want the format to be HH:MM.

```
class SearchTimeSlotsForm(forms.Form):
  available_from = forms.TimeField(
      widget=TimeInput(attrs={'class': 'unbold-form'}), 
      initial=time(0)
  )
  available_till = forms.TimeField(
      widget=TimeInput(attrs={'class': 'unbold-form'}), 
      initial=time(23,59,59)
  )
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a [format](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#std-setting-TIME_INPUT_FORMATS) to the [widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.TimeInput):

```py
class SearchTimeSlotsForm(forms.Form):
  available_from = forms.TimeField(
      widget=forms.TimeInput(attrs={'class': 'unbold-form'}, format='%H:%M'), 
      initial=time(0),
  )
  available_till = forms.TimeField(
      widget=forms.TimeInput(attrs={'class': 'unbold-form'}, format='%H:%M'), 
      initial=time(23,59,59),
  )
```